# Создать объект с ключами из списка JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, dict

Есть следующий список:

```
let lst = ["km-m", "km-cm", "km-mm"]
```

На выходе необходимо получить словарь следующего типа:

```
let myDict = {
    "km-m": {
        "km": 0,
        "m": 0
    },
    "km-cm": {
        "km": 0,
        "cm": 0
    },
    "km-mm": {
        "km": 0,
        "mm": 0
    },
};
```

Пишу следующий цикл и не знаю как наполнить словарь

```
for(let i=0; i < joinList.length; i++) {
     let template = joinList[i].split('-');
     console.log(joinList[i]);
     Object.assign(convertData, {joinList[i]: 0});
 };
```

В цикле ощибка, не пойму почему нельзя поставить ключем lst[0] например.
Прошу помочь исправить код или предложить альтернативное решение
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{joinList[i]: 0}` — так будет синтаксическая ошибка, потому что в качестве ключей объекта можно использовать или строки, или идентификаторы (т.е. то, что разрешено как имя переменной). Если вы хотите использовать в качестве ключей произвольные выражения (в том числе переменные), их нужно заключать в квадратные скобки: `{ [joinList[i]]: 0}`. Тогда вычисленное значение выражения (или его строковой вариант, если результатом будет не строка) будет использовано в качестве ключа.

Можно так:

```js
const lst = ["km-m", "km-cm", "km-mm"];
const obj = {};

for (const key of lst) {
  const subkeys = key.split('-');
  obj[key] = { [subkeys[0]]: 0, [subkeys[1]]: 0 };
}

console.log(obj);
```

Или так:

```js
const lst = ["km-m", "km-cm", "km-mm"];

const obj = lst.reduce(
  (obj, key) => {
    const [subkey1, subkey2] = key.split('-');
    obj[key] = { [subkey1]: 0, [subkey2]: 0 };
    return obj;
  },
  {}
);

console.log(obj);
```

P.S. Создание словаря с параметрами:

```js
const correlations = {
  km: {
    m:  1000,
    cm: 100000,
    mm: 1000000,
  },
}
const list = ['km-m', 'km-cm', 'km-mm'];
const number = 3;

console.log(getDic(number, list, correlations));

function getDic(number, list, correlations) {
  const obj = {};

  for (const key of list) {
    const [subkey1, subkey2] = key.split('-');;
    obj[key] = {
      [subkey1]: number,
      [subkey2]: number * correlations[subkey1][subkey2]
    };
  }

  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я пробовал так, но писал key через точку) Может вы подкините идею, как ниписать функцию или класс, чтобы этот лист обрабатывался в такой словарь, а вместо нулей значения другие? Допустим взять lst[0] чтобы на выходе получился такой словарь {"km-m": {"km": 1, "m": 1000}}. Скажем, в одним киллометре 1000 метров.

Comment: Не уверен, что правильно понял, но попытался добавить пример в конец ответа. Нам нужно три параметра: число, которое мы будет пересчитывать, массив со списком ключей и служебный объект с соотношением между ключами (туда можно добавлять нужные меры — длины, веса, времени и т.д.). В примере мы создаём словарь с набором соотношений для 3 километров.

Comment: добавь пояснение, почему в вопросе `{joinList[i]: 0}` не работало, а у тебя работает

Comment: Добавил в начало вопроса.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, _произвольные выражения_ - в итоге все равно в строку приведутся, а то сейчас можно подумать, что можно использовать любое выражение и все ожидаемо отработает

Comment: Ну, я там написал, что в результате будет использован строковой вариант.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, что-то я пропустил эту часть

Comment: Сделал её более явной)

Answer (score -2):

```js
let lst = ["km-m", "km-cm", "km-mm"];

console.log(Object.fromEntries(lst.map(m=>[m,Object.fromEntries(m.split('-').map(s=>[s,0]))])));
```